# not able to understand why TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registerVersion') this error is coming

Tags: reactjs

not able to understand why TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registerVersion') this error is coming

i am trying to implement firebase

Comment: Welcome to SO. Put your codes here so we can reproduce the error you get.

Comment: import { initializeApp,getApps } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";

var firebaseConfig = {
   sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);